Indicative past or past subjunctive (if there was a plan to rescue her or he had a mission to rescue her)

I would probably say "He succeeded in rescuing her" rather than "He
rescued her" if there was a plan to save her or he had a
mission to rescue her. [my sentence]

I assume that both was and had are in the past indicative mood, not the past subjunctive mood. Is my assumption correct?
It seems that native English speakers sometimes use "was" as a substitute for the subjunctive "were" in ordinary conversation, hence my question.

Yes, they are past indicative. But you could backshift : "... if there had been a plan to save her or he had been on a mission to rescue her."

Yes this is a basic lesson. Most contemporary speakers use indicative following "if". See e.g. this question and this search.
